# Python Astral Calculations for Sunrise, two different times same date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I wrote a solar panel adjustment program that moves the panel with the sun position.  When I calculate the sunrise for the next day (the night before), it's different than when I calculate it again in the morning.  It's off by a little over a minute.

The program was running the "night function" the next morning instead of starting the "day function".  Through my troubleshooting I figured out that the sunrise time was changing depending on if I calculated it the night before or in the morning.

```
    ast = Astral()
    city_Name = 'Cleveland'
    local_City = ast[city_Name]

    def get_Current_Time():
        eastern = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
        curr_Time = datetime.now(eastern)
        return curr_Time

    def solar_Adjust_Deactive():
        global local_City
        curr_Time = get_Current_Time()
        calc_Tomorrow = curr_Time + timedelta(days=1)
        sun_Position_Tomorrow = local_City.sun(local=True, date = calc_Tomorrow)
        solar_Sunrise_Tomorrow = sun_Position_Tomorrow.get('sunrise')

    def main_Function():
        global local_City
        sun_Position = local_City.sun(local=True)
        current_Time = get_Current_Time()
        solar_Sunrise = sun_Position.get('sunrise')
```

Expected results would be the sunrise time be the same, whether I calculate it the night before or the next morning.

Actual Results:
Sunrise Tomorrow  2019-04-30 06:23:29-04:00 (Calculated night before)
Sunrise Today 2019-04-30 06:24:38-04:00 (Calculated morning of)

Comment: Your code example calls the function `get_Current_time()`. Is this function part of a python package, or is it defined in your own code (not included here)?

Comment: It's defined in my code, just not shown here.  The get_Current_Time() I added it to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring of the [`astral.Location.sun`](https://astral.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#astral.Location.sun) function states that a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) object (i.e. date only) is expected for the `date` input parameter. It seems to me that the function gets confused and produces incorrect results when a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types) object (i.e. date plus time) is given as input. This might explain the strange behaviour in your code.

So try replacing `calc_Tomorrow = curr_Time + timedelta(days=1)` in your code with `calc_Tomorrow = curr_Time.date() + timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: That worked!  This morning my output was correct!  Thanks that was driving me crazy!
Sunrise Tomorrow  2019-05-01 06:23:18-04:00 (Calculated last night)
Sunrise Today 2019-05-01 06:23:18-04:00 (Calculated this morning)